# DNA data input for NN, one hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Faced a problem what sounds like a challenging task for me. Have a huge dataset of DNA with A,G,T,C structure, 4 totally different categories as input. It looks like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 … 1.000+
A A G G G G G G G
G G C C C C C C C
T T C C C C C C C
G G A A A A A A A
T T C C C C C C C
C C T T T T T T T
T T C C C C C C C
…
30.000+
```

Would like to ask about the advice about data processing. Should it be represented as numerical or one hot encoding with such huge dimensionality? Kind of [0,0,0,1] as A, [0,0,1,0] as G and etc., or just 0, 1, 2, 3? Talking about NN - would like to start from simple one to modern and deeper. Typical numerical representation is easily done by pandas, sklearn libraries in few lines of code, but converting it to the one hot encoding, for such huge dataset, looks like an interesting task. By using pd.get_dummies from a (1019, 27041) shape we obtain (1019, 54082), and can not understand why shape increased only 2 times when we have 4 different letters. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2x increase instead of 4x increase is because you only have 2 categories in each of the series. (In your example, A and G in the first row, G and C in the second, T and C in the third and so on)

The below example will give a better understanding of the number of additional columns

```
In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'C': [1, 2, 3]})                                                                       

In [39]: df                                                                                                                                                    
Out[39]: 
   A  B  C
0  a  b  1
1  b  a  2
2  a  c  3

In [40]: pd.get_dummies(df)                                                                                                                                    
Out[40]: 
   C  A_a  A_b  B_a  B_b  B_c
0  1    1    0    0    1    0
1  2    0    1    1    0    0
2  3    1    0    0    0    1
```